# DateTime object is blank

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a date to a DateTime Object. My code works fine on my localhost (php version 5.3) but returns a blank DateTime object on my remote server (php version 5.2.14). Am I missing something really obvious?

```
<?php
   $d = '2010-01-01';
   $n = new DateTime ( $d );
   print_r($n);   
?>
```

// result on localhost:

```
 DateTime Object ( [date] => 2010-01-01 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )
```

// result on remotehost:

```
 DateTime Object ( ) // is blank
```

UPDATED EXAMPLE::

Maybe I'm missing something really simple. I've tried it w/ the suggestion from Pooyan but I must be dense:

```
function changeDate (  ){

$arr = array('2010-01-01' , '2010-01-02' , '2010-01-03');

foreach ( $arr as $k=>$v ){
    $v = new DateTime ( $v );
    $v->format('Y-m-d');
    $arr[$k] = $v;
}

return $arr;  

}

print_r( changeDate( ) ); // works in php 5.3 but still returns a blank DateTime Object in php 5.2
```

Comment: you don't have to call date_default_timezone_set multiple times. It sets the default timezone for all functions in a script...

Comment: What does `$value["date"]` contain?

Comment: could you provide example dates and how you are checking the datetime value afterwards? Ie, so it can be replicated.

Comment: What happens if you do `new DateTime ( strtotime($v) );`? and what is your full php version? e.g. ( 5.2. **10** )

Comment: And maybe its time to: http://bugs.php.net/report.php

Comment: `$arr[$k] = $v->format('Y-m-d')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$v->format('Y-m-d')` doesn't change the object but returns a string with the DateTime formatted in the given format.

So this should work:

```
function changeDate () {
    $input = array('2010-01-01' , '2010-01-02' , '2010-01-03');

    foreach($input as $v) {
        $date = new DateTime($v);
        $output[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    return $output;  
}

print_r(changeDate());
```

Although that gives you the input array back, so it's pretty pointless.

Answer (score 2):

with PHP 5.2 you have to use:

```
$d = '2010-01-01';
$n = new DateTime ( $d )
echo $n->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Please see my updated code above w/ your suggestion...it still doesn't work, though

Answer (score 0):

Probably this reply is arriving too late. I was having the same issue, and the problem was in `print_r`, not in the `DateTime` object itself. It seems using `print_r` and/or `var_dump` in DateTime objects on PHP 5.2 doesn't work. Hence the suggestion about using

```
echo $n->format('Y-m-d'); // (1)
```

instead of

```
print_r($n)
```

If (1) shows the expected value, then your object is fine.

You can find more info here:
[new DateTime returns empty DateTime instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584625/new-datetime-returns-empty-datetime-instance)

Comment: I don't agree with you. In my case, I am sure the problem is in `DateTime` in 5.2

Comment: @whiteletters and blankspaces, could you elaborate a bit more, please? In PHP 5.2.17 I'm sure that, at least, I get blank contents when trying to print_r a valid DateTime object.

Answer (score -1):

you should be aware that there is a method called `getLastErrors()` that would hold any errors created with `DateTime`

try the following:

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset( $value['date']))
    {
         try
         {
             $rows[$key]['date'] = new DateTime($value['date']);
             if(count(($e = $rows[$key]['date']->getLastErrors())) > 0)
             {
                   throw new Exception($e[0]);
             }
         }catch(Exception $e)
         {
             echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
             continue;
         }
         date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    }
}
```

and see if that sheds some light.

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be what I need to get this to work under php 5.2, as the code works on php 5.3 but not 5.2

Comment: He is saying it's not working on PHP 5.2. DateTime::getLastErrors() only works on PHP >= 5.3