# DateTime in PHP 5.2.17 creating an empty date object

Tags: php, datetime

In my localhost, which operates under PHP 5.4.7, the `new DateTime()` is creating an object with current date with no problem.

But in my live server, which works with PHP 5.2.17, the `new DateTime()` is creating an empty date object.

I read some topics on SO concerning this issue, but I am not convinced by their accepted answers. They think the problem comes from `var_dump` and `print_r` and that they should be replaced by `echo`.

[new DateTime returns empty DateTime instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584625/new-datetime-returns-empty-datetime-instance)

Any insights regarding this subject? Is there another alternative to `new DateTime()` to return the current date in all versions of PHP.
Your time and consideration are highly appreciated.

Comment: They are right, listen to them.

Comment: @Marek, I did to no avail, `echo` tells me that my object is empty.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces: [This](http://3v4l.org/8dC6E) works on all versions of PHP that support DateTime.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces Did you try `$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it was already said, PHP version `5.2.x` return "empty" DateTime object if you print it, **[see demo](http://3v4l.org/BR6fn)**.

But why would you print out the object? Just format it.

```php
$dt = new DateTime('today');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

**[See demo](http://3v4l.org/WiC2o)**.